# VWP Visit to USA- visiting Girlfriend

Tags: usa, esta, us-visa-waiver-program, uk-citizens, 90-180-visa-rules

I would just like some clarification on a travel plan I have in a few weeks. I have been in a year long relationship with a girl from Chicago, USA. We met in London last year and have done a number of short term trips back and forth between London and USA. Each trip has been for a matter of weeks and I have not stayed in USA longer than 10 days. I have visited 4 times in the past year.

I am leaving London at the beginning of June to visit America for the summer, spend time with my girlfriend and do some trips with her around the country. I am leaving my job in a few weeks and using the summer as a time to think about my next career move and work out the direction of my job. My lease in the UK ends at the end of september (proof of tie to UK) and I have ample enough funds to cover the cost of the trip. I also have a flight booked for the end of August (84 day trip)

Although I will use APC at the airport in Chicago, do you think I will have any issues if a CBP decides to ask anything?! From experience, the questioning when using APC seems to be v light.

Any thoughts would be much appreciated.

Comment: From my own experiences I don't see you being denied entry with your profile even if you are questioned by a CBP officer unless you have other issues (like a criminal record etc) not highlighted in your write-up. You should be fine.

Comment: Thanks very much for clarifying. No criminal record, have had no problem entering the USA on my trips this year.

Comment: Your lease isn't much of a tie to the UK. Essentially, you're saying "That proves I'll go back to the UK because, if I don't, I'll be wasting a month's rent." But you're already "wasting" _three_ months of rent by spending all that time in the US -- what difference would one more month make?

Comment: I would check the delivery services, and ask to have an original sent ASAP via whichever is fastest to your location. You can continue to research whether originals are really required while it is in transit.